# Set BackgroundColor with Pattern Image results in black/transparent screen on iOS7

Tags: ios, uiimage

I'm trying to set a background image for my app. I'm using this code in my ViewDidLoad:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"TablePlate"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

When executed under iOS8 it works fine (for some reason).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this code instead of using a graphics context:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TablePlate"]];

}
```

Comment: the background image is repeating itself. Can you plz mention how can i fill the image entirely in to the button?